# Simple aspect-oriented duck-typing in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, aop

Do I need a heavy weight [aspect oriented programming library](https://github.com/gcao/aspector) to duck-type methods with before and after join point advice, or can I do it in a few lines of Ruby?

For example, I have the following function:

```
def add_them(a,b)
     a + b
end
```

I want to duck-type `add_them()` with a before join point so it type-checks before executing the main body:

```
 if (a.class != b.class)
   puts "DANGER"
 end
```

The naive way of duck-typing destroys the original `add_them()`. Ideally I want to end up with:

```
def foo
   #before join point code
   #original body of foo
   #after join point code
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

First, if you're mixing a module into your class, you can simply call `super` to call the overridden method:

```
class Foo
  def bar(a, b)
    a + b
  end
end

module TypeEnforcer
  def bar(a, b)
    raise "Wrong type!" unless a.is_a? Fixnum && b.is_a? Fixnum
    super
  end
end

Foo.send :include, TypeEnforcer
```

If you're monkey patching by reopening the same class, though, you would use `alias_method` to create a "backup" of the method you're overwriting:

```
class Foo
  alias_method :orig_bar, :bar
  def bar(a, b)
    raise "Wrong type!" unless a.is_a? Fixnum && b.is_a? Fixnum
    orig_bar(a, b)
  end
end
```

Finally, while this doesn't answer your question, you might be interested in [contracts.ruby](https://github.com/egonSchiele/contracts.ruby) which uses Ruby metaprogramming magic to add type contracts to methods. It does have a bit of performance overhead, but it's a very clean way to express this kind of behavior.

Comment: `include` will make `TypeEnforcer` a *superclass* of `Foo`. You need to use `prepend`.

Comment: alias_method was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! Great for memoization too it seems, and it works on Ruby1.9